# Exclude elements that appear in another sequence

Tags: linq

I have the following sequence:

`public static List<string> IgnoredSubCodes => new List<string> {"HERE", "NOT_HERE"};`

```
var demographics = personify.CUS_DEMOGRAPHIC.Where(demographic =>
                    clubIds.Contains(demographic.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID) &&
                    distinctCodes.Contains(demographic.DEMOGRAPHIC_CODE) &&
                    distinctProgramYears.Contains(demographic.USR_PROGRAM_YEAR) &&
                    !demographic.DEMOGRAPHIC_SUBCODE.Any(x => PersonifyConstants.DemographicCodes.DemographicSubCodes.IgnoredSubCodes));
```

The last line above won't work but I'd like to be able to say "don't include any demographic subcode that appears in this list". How can I do that? I've tried a couple of different clauses with .Where and .Any but I'm not understanding the permutation I need. I could hardcode it inside that query as `demographic.DEMOGRAPHIC_SUBCODE != "HERE" && demographic.DEMOGRAPHIC_SUBCODE != "NOT_HERE"` but I'd like to have all the exclusions in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this? Hope it will work.

```
var demographics = personify.CUS_DEMOGRAPHIC.Where(demographic =>
                clubIds.Contains(demographic.MASTER_CUSTOMER_ID) &&
                distinctCodes.Contains(demographic.DEMOGRAPHIC_CODE) &&
                distinctProgramYears.Contains(demographic.USR_PROGRAM_YEAR) &&
                !PersonifyConstants.DemographicCodes.DemographicSubCodes.IgnoredSubCodes.Any(code => code == demographic.DEMOGRAPHIC_SUBCODE));
```